# What is the difference between the delay and the jitter in the context of real time applications?

Tags: networking, streaming, real-time

According to Wikipedia **Jitter is the undesired deviation from true periodicity of an assumed periodic signal**, according to a papper on QoS that I am reading **jitter is reffered to as delay variation**. Are there any definition of the jitter in the context of real time applications? Are there applications that are sensitive to jitter but not sensitive to delay? If for example a streaming application use some kind of buffer to store packets before show them to the user, is it possible that this application is not sensitive to delay but is sensitive to jitter?

Answer (score 9):

Delay: Is the amount of time data(signal) takes to reach the destination. Now a higher delay generally means congestion of some sort of breaking of the communication link.

Jitter: Is the variation of delay time. This happens when a system is not in deterministic state eg. Video Streaming suffers from jitter a lot because the size of data transferred is quite large and hence no way of saying how long it might take to transfer.

If your application is sensitive to jitter it is definitely sensitive to delay.

Comment: "_If your application is sensitive to jitter it is definitely sensitive to delay._" That is not completely accurate. VoIP applications can actually handle delay pretty well, but the are extremely sensitive to jitter, even with very little delay. For instance, VoIP should have no problems with a 250 ms delay, but, even where you have a 10 ms delay, jitter will give it problems.

Answer (score 4):

In Real-time Protocol (RTP, RFC3550), a header contains a timestamp field.  The value of it usually comes from a monotonically incremented counter and the frequency of the increment is the clock-rate. This clock-rate must be the same all over the participant wants something with the timestamp field. The counters have different base offsets, because the start time may different or they contains it because of security reason, etc... All in all we say the clocks are not syncronized.

To show it in an example consider if we refer to snd_timestamp and rcv_timestamp the most recent packet sender timestamp from the RTP header field and receiver timestamp generated by the receiver using the same clock-rate.
The wrong conclusion is that

delay_in_timestamp_unit = rcv_timestamp - snd_timestamp

If the receiver and sender clock-rate has different base offset (and they have), this not gives you the delay, also it doesn't consider the wrap around the 32bit unsigned integer.

But monitoring the time for delivering packets is somehow necessary if we want a proper playout adaption algorithm or if we want to detect and avoid congestions.

Also note that if we have syncronized clocks delay_in_timestamp_unit might be not punctually represent the pure network delay, because of components at the sender or at the receiver side retaining these packets after and/or before the timestamp added and/or exemined. So if you calculate a 2seconds delay between the participant, but you know your network delay is around 100ms, then your packets suffer additional delays at the sender or/and at the receiver side. But that additional delay is somehow (or at least you hope that it is) constant, so the only delay changes in time is - hopefully - the network delay. So you should not say that if packet delay > 500ms then we have a congestion, because you have no idea what is the actual network delay if you use only one packet sender and receiver timestamp information.

But the difference between the delays of two consecutive packets might gives you some information about weather something wrong in the network or not.

diff_delay = delay_t0 - delay_t1

if diff_delay equals to 0 the delay is the same, if it greater than 0 the newly arrived packets needed more time then the previous one, and if it smaller than 0 it needed less time.

And from that relative information based on two consecutive delays you could say something.

How you determine the difference between two delay if the clocks are not syncronized?

Consider you stored the last timestamps in rcv_timestamp_t1 and snd_timestamp_t1

diff_delay = (rcv_timestamp_t0 - snd_timestamp_t0) - (rcv_timestamp_t1 - snd_timestamp_t1)

but that would be problem without maintaining the base offsets of the sender and the receiver, so reordering it:

diff_delay = (rcv_timestamp_t0 - rcv_timestamp_t1) - (snd_timestamp_t0 - snd_timestamp_t1)

and here you can subtract rcv timestamps from each other and it eliminates the offset rcv and snd contain, and then you can extract the rcv_diff from snd_diff and it gives you the information about the difference of the delays of two consecutive packets in the unit of the clock-rate.

Now, according to RFC3550 jitter is "An estimate of the statistical variance of the RTP data packet interarrival time".

In order to finally get to the point your question is 
"What is the difference between the delay and the jitter in the context of real time applications?"

Tiny note, but real-time applications usually refer to systems processing data in a range of nanoseconds, so I think you refer to end-to-end systems.

Also despite of several altered definition of jitter, it all uses the difference of the delays of arrived packets and thus provide you information about the relative changes of the network delay, meanwhile delay itself is an absolute value of the time of delivery.